# Authorization with Radius Server

Tags: web-applications, radius, freeradius

I have made a web application that i need to authenticate through a radius server.I am using freeRADIUS for Linux and the dialupadmin gui and mysql at the back-end.

My question is, how can i get authorization info from the RADIUSresponse.
How and what type of groups i can create on the radius server that must be returned in order to maintain an Access Control List on the Web Application.

I need to understand if RADIUS can return the Roles and Groups information to my web application and how.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks